# Invoke "superclass" constructor in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, polymorphism

I just got into JavaScript and I'm kind of puzzled by its object-oriented behavior.
I was just trying to create a class `Point2D` with `x`,`y` members and extend it with a `Point3D` class with `x`,`y`,`z` members.
The behavior I'm trying to achieve is something like, let's say it in C#:

```
class Point2D
{ 
   int x, y;
   public Point2D(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
}
class Point3D : Point2D
{
    int z;
    public Point3D(int x, int y, int z) : base(x, y) { this.z = z; }
}
```

I read a lot of stuff but I don't seem to really find what I'm looking for.
Here's what I've come up to so far:

```
function Point2D(x, y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
Point2D.prototype.constructor = Point2D;
function Point3D(x, y, z) { Point2D.prototype.constructor.call(this); this.z = z; }
Point3D.prototype = new A(); // see latter explanation
Point3D.prototype.constructor = B;
var p = new Point3D(10, 20, 30);
```

Which is obviously wrong.

Now, I know I should do something like `Point3D.prototype = new A(x, y)` but I don't want to create a prototype with *fixed* `x`,`y` coordinates and variable `z`.
It must be very simple, but I'm just not getting it, I can't seem to call the superclass constructor or to make it behave properly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

JavaScript's prototypal inheritance provides a couple of different flexible ways to perform the kind of polymorphic constructors you're looking for. In your particular example, you want something like this:

```
function Point2D(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

function Point3D(x, y, z) {
  Point2D.call(this, x, y);
  this.z = z;
}
```

Fussing with explicitly setting the `constructor` on the `prototype` is not strictly necessary here. (It is really only necessary when you are creating the prototype "all at once" -- e.g., with an object.)

For a detailed discussion of object-oriented JavaScript, I'd recommend Nicholas Zakas' *Principles of Object-Oriented Programming in JavaScript* (ebook) or the discussion of prototypes and inheritance in his other book, *Professional JavaScript for Web Developers*.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was going nuts and it was that simple!
I'll definitely give a read to at least one of those books.